# List of All running processes in Android

Tags: android, process

How to get the list of Android system's All running process including System launched processes?

I tried to get the list using below code:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

This gave me the List of processes such as `com.android.phone`, `com.android.chrome`, etc.

But when I run a `ps` command in my `adb shell`, I could see whole other bunch of processes running. I am attaching the screenshot of all those processes running in my system.
[image: Running processes in my devices]

As one can see, there are several Android System's processes are also running like `/system/bin/vold` and `/system/bin/installed`, etc.

However, these are not reported by `getRunningAppProcesses()` API. In its docs, it says that this API:

> **Returns a list of application processes that are running on the device.**

Does this mean it won't return "system process"? And if that is the case what option developer can have to iterate over "ALL" process running on Android?

-- **What else I tried:**
Tried with 2 more APIs from `ActivityManager`:

1. `getRecentTasks(int maxNum)` and it's variant.

But Android docs warns about its use as below:

> **This method was deprecated in API level 21.**
>
> **As of LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available to third party applications**

2. `getRunningServices(int maxNum)`

But both of these could not give me names like `/system/bin/debuggerd`, etc.

**NOTE: I am running Android-4.2 Jellybean, on Non-Rooted device.**

Comment: There is no API for getting a list of _all_ the running processes on the Android system, as the internal processes are not relevant to a userspace application. The only way to get them would be to run a shell command on a rooted device.

Comment: @corsair992: Is your statement is an outcome of your own experience? Or do you have "official" Android reference which clearly states this? If we can get the valid reference, that will be used as pointer for next set of developers trying this. Because I was able to run "ps" on shell without rooting, I was under impression that Android Framework must have something similar for Apps too.

Comment: It's based on my knowledge of the APIs. You may be able to run the shell command without root (I haven't tried this, and it may be possible), but there is no API for this that I ever heard of.

Comment: Yes, if you see the screenshot that I attached, I actually ran "ps" by doing "adb shell". So, I can say, we can run shell commands without root, as My device is non-rooted. Since listing process is just kind of "read" opration, hence I felt it should be available through Android API.

Comment: I was talking about performing it from inside an application. It might be doable without root as well, but it will have to be tested. Also, you will need to test if the "ps" tool exists in every version of Android. I have already explained why it doesn't make sense to make it an API.

Answer (score 11):

By calling an API from `ActivityManager`, you're only getting the applications which registered with it - that is, UI activities - and not *all* the processes. Those you see with a non-reverse DNS name, but a path (e.g. `/system/bin/*`) are native daemons, started by `init`, and left out of the `ActivityManager`.

One way around this is to get the list of processes directly from `/proc` (just like toolbox's `ps` does it). This requires iterating programmatically over the directories there, (i.e. `/proc/[0-9]*`), and pruning out the kernel threads. Kernel threads are those with a `PPID` of 2, so they're easy. Native daemons will have a `PPID` of 1. Applications will have a `PPID` of Zygote.

Reference: [NewAndroidBook.com](http://newandroidbook.com)

Comment: I tried using Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ps"); And I saved it's output using BufferedReader and then looped over data to it gave me what I was looking for.Since it is not best solution I did not post it. Anyways, let me try your solution too....@Technologeeks

Comment: You're doing a less elegant solution to achieve the same outcome. It's better to iterate over /proc - not all devices are guaranteed to have ps, but /proc is a given. Plus the output of ps might change in formatting - but /proc's won't.

Comment: @AADProgramming /system/bin/ps worke for you ? I am getting only system apps in the output I want root and system apps process in output and unforunelty ps command doen't work. any idea about it ?