# measuring time it takes for android intent to run app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am currently developing an app to measure the advantage in terms of start up time on board applications have over their web based counterparts. I decided to use intents to fire up the Youtube app and web interface but i am currently having a hard time measuring the start-up time. I'm a total newby by the way.

```
package com.example.thabo.app_optimization;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String TestVid_ID = "giYeaKsXnsI";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void watchYoutubeVideo(String id, String runType){
        Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id));
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
        if (runType == "app") {
            startActivity(appIntent);}

        else
            startActivity(webIntent);

        display();
    }

    /**
     * Method to initialize the application
     */
    public void RUN_APP(View view) {

        watchYoutubeVideo(TestVid_ID, "app");

    }

    public void RUN_WEB(View view){
        watchYoutubeVideo(TestVid_ID, "web");
    }

    /**
    * Method to display the name of the current activity onscreen
     * */
    private void display() {
        TextView Activity = (TextView) findViewById(
                R.id.Activity);

        Activity.setText(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this i suggest you to creat a background service, then you start some "clock" there to measure the time ->>[Android - To measure the time between the two button clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965065/android-to-measure-the-time-between-the-two-button-clicks)! To check if the process is opened ( then stop your "clock" ) you will have to iterator the entire process list on android([List of All running processes in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885482/list-of-all-running-processes-in-android))